# curl command: "Failed to create room"

Tags: json, curl, cisco

I am studying for Cisco DevNet certification, and I have the problem below:

```
$ curl https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages -X POST -H "Authorization:Bearer MD...4" --data "toPersonEmail=jul...@hotmail.com" --data "text=Hi%20from%20DevNet"

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   212  100   147  100    65    106     47  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   

153{"message":"Failed to create room.","errors":[{"description":"Failed to create room."}],"trackingId":"ROUTER_5DE8B491-8B47-01BB-3B54-B39F39FD3B54"}
```

The correct output should look something like this:

```
{
   "id":"Y2l...mNh",
   "roomId":"Y2l...WMy",
   "toPersonEmail":"someone@cisco.com",
   "roomType":"direct",
   "text":"Hi from DevNet",
   "personId":"Y2l...ODc",
   "personEmail":"labs@chatbot.land",
   "created":"2018-12-13T23:32:43.377Z"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are give wrong Authorization:Bearer 
In website you have check that you are your own Authorization:Bearer but that can not visiable for us when we copy and paste to cmd then that Authorization:Bearer we can userd for it may be that's the error and that's why you got something wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to send message to yourself, it will not work. Try and to set "toPersonEmail" to a different WebEx Teams contact.
You can also check this website for your solution:
https://community.cisco.com/t5/devnet-sandbox/cisco-webex-api-excersice-failed-to-create-a-room/td-p/3919295